# How to use LINQ.Where for specific indexes

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, expression, conditional-statements

As the title says i need a LINQ expression which is going to check only few indexes of array. I currently have it like this :

```
int[] a = b.Where(c => c % 4 == (int)Cards.CardSuits.Club).ToArray();
```

those are not my actual variables names i just made it a little bit shorter.
I just need to check `b[2]` up to `b[b.length-1]`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean in your last sentence - my answer just provides an example in terms of checking the index of each entry. If that doesn't do what you want, please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use the index within your predicate instead of the value, use the overload of `Where` which accepts a predicate which checks a value/index pair:

```
int[] a = b.Where((value, index) => index % 4 == (int) Cards.CardSuits.Club)
           .ToArray();
```

(I'd strongly recommend you model cards differently though - consider either a struct or a class with `Suit` and `Rank` properties. Then you can check whether the suit is clubs in a *much* more natural way...)

---

If you *actually* wanted to keep your existing filter, but just ignore the first two elements of the source, you probably want `Skip`:

```
int[] a = b.Skip(2)
           .Where(c => c % 4 == (int) Cards.CardSuits.Club)
           .ToArray();
```

Comment: if `b` has values of 51-36 
`int[] a = b.Where((value, index) => index % 4 == (int)Cards.CardSuits.Club).ToArray();` will have values 51 and 36
while `int[] a = b.Where(c => c % 4 == (int)Cards.CardSuits.Club).ToArray();` has value 36 why is that ? is it because we are dividing the index instead of the value ?

Comment: @KOPEUE: Well the first is dealing with just the *index* of the entry in the source, and the latter is dealing with the *value* of the entries. Note that you haven't told us what's in the array, or what result you were expecting, which makes it harder to help you.

Comment: I don't see `value` being used in the predicate function. Is something missing there?

Comment: @ubi: Nope, because the title of the question is "How to use LINQ.Where for specific indexes" - which I took to mean the OP wanted to filter by index rather than by value. Have added an answer to a different interpretation of the question now...

Comment: `int[] a = b.Where((value, index) => index >= 2 && value % 4 == (int)Cards.CardSuits.Club).ToArray();` this one works for me also using the value (i need it but you are right i didn't mention it)

Comment: @KOPEUE: That will skip the first *two* entries, not the first one. It's not clear whether you're expecting things to be 1-based rather than 0-indexed...

Comment: I actually needed the first 2 entries my mistake i will change the index from  `b[1]` to `b[2]`

Comment: @KOPEUE: I would *strongly* urge you to spend time editing your question to make it clearer. At the moment it's extremely unlcear what you're really trying to do.

Comment: I just edited the indexes nothing more and why is your first expression not better than the second ?

Comment: @KOPEUE: If you just want to skip some entries, I believe most people would find the version with Skip/Take simpler go read.

Answer (score 1):

You say you just need to check b[1] up to b[b.length-1], so you're just skipping the first ("[0]") element, right? For that do just this:

```
b.Skip(1).Where(...)
```